# How can add rule to log all incoming traffic?

Tags: nftables

The nftables status  in my os:

```
sudo systemctl status nftables
● nftables.service - nftables
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nftables.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Fri 2022-11-04 11:01:47 HKT; 1s ago
       Docs: man:nft(8)
             http://wiki.nftables.org
    Process: 3780 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nft -f /etc/nftables.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 3780 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 7ms

Nov 04 11:01:47 debian systemd[1]: Starting nftables...
Nov 04 11:01:47 debian systemd[1]: Finished nftables.
```

Now i want to log all incoming traffic:

```
sudo nft add rule filter input log
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
add rule filter input log
         ^^^^^^
```

List the configuration file `nftables.conf`:

```
cat /etc/nftables.conf
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0;
    }
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0;
    }
    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0;
    }
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: `cat /proc/net/dev | tail -n +3 | awk 'BEGIN{ print "NIC inbound-data-traffic(bytes)  outbound-data-traffic(bytes)"} {print $1,$2,$10}' | column -t`   Will this meet your needs?

Comment: What i need is to set the log for nftables ,what you provider is the statistics info not log info.

Comment: I am sorry for not understanding your meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is in the `inet` [family](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#ADDRESS_FAMILIES) (representing the combination of IPv4+IPv6 together) so the family parameter `inet` is needed, else it defaults to `ip`:

> If an identifier is specified without an address family, the `ip` family
> is used by default.

As there's no `ip filter` table nor `ip filter input` chain, this command:

> ```
> nft add rule filter input log
> ```

fails.

The proper command would be (as root or with `sudo`. All commands below are to be run as root or with `sudo`)...

```
nft add rule inet filter input log
```

... **but** the command above is usually dangerous because it can generate too much logs and flood the filesystem storing these logs and should not be used as is unless prepared for it.

It could be better, for this case where no actual firewalling is done, to not log packets part of an already existing flow (ie: packets in *established* conntrack state) leaving new,related (eg: ICMP errors sent back) and invalid packets. This is done using [conntrack](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#CONNTRACK_EXPRESSIONS)'s help. For good measure also [limit](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#LIMIT_STATEMENT) the number of logs (eg: a maximum of 20 per minute). I'm also adding three times the [`counter`](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#COUNTER_STATEMENT) statement, to be able to display back (using `nft list ruleset`) statistics about the difference in volume with each added filter before it reaches the log statement. They are not needed.

```
nft add rule inet filter input counter ct state != established counter limit rate 20/minute counter log
```

To keep this for later reuse, the previous file `/etc/nftables.conf` can be edited using the output of `nft -s list ruleset` (but the `flush ruleset` command should not be removed) and the *nftables* service restarted (`systemctl restart nftables`) or the file directly reloaded (`nft -f /etc/nftables.conf`) to revert to its content.

Comment: How can log only the connected ip address in the log file ?

Comment: Your question is about using the `log` nftables statement. This statement doesn't do what you are now later asking: it will log all properties of the packet.